# AngularJS: Share factory between multiple modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a module called App which injects two other modules called *factories* and *controllers*:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["factories", "controllers", "directives"])
.run(function ($rootScope, userFactory) {
    userFactory.property = "someKickstartValue";
});
```

The *factories* module holds all factories:

```
var factories = angular.module("factories", []),
factory = factories.factory("testFactory", {
     property: "someValue"
});
```

And the *controllers* module holds all controllers:

```
var controllers = angular.module("controllers", ["factories"]),
controller = controllers.controller("controller", function ($scope, testFactory) {
    console.log(testFactory.property); // Returns "Some Value" and not 
                                       // "someKickstartValue" as expected.
});
```

**The actual Question:**

Why does the "someKickstartValue" not apply to the controllers? As far as I do understand the module *app* has it's own *testFactory* instance and the module *controllers* has it's own as well, so there can't be any information shared between modules via factories. Is there a way around, or have I made a mistake?

Comment: In the first line, starting `var app` you have mis-spelled "factories"

Comment: @Mawg Thanks. I changed it. Should be correct now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the "factories" dependency of the controller.

```
var controllers = angular.module("controllers", []),
controller = controllers.controller("controller", function ($scope, testFactory) {
    console.log(testFactory.property); // Returns "someKickstartValue" as expected
});
```

Because I now do not declare *factories* as dependency, the *controllers* module doesn't create it's own instance of *factories* and has access to the instance of the *app* module which injects the *controllers* module.

Comment: Are you sure that that is the correct way to do it? By injecting into the app, you are injecting into all controllers of that app. If only some controllers need the "factories" dependency, then why not inject into only those controllers, and not the entire app? Please note that I am no Angular guru.

Comment: @Mawg In the meantime I've switched to angular 4. So this is not fresh in my mind anymore. But as far as I remember you might be right. Just try out what happens, when you remove the `factories` injection in the first line of the opening post.

Comment: I want to make the switch myself, but am not sure if  the time is right yet. Do you know, for instance, if Angular 4 can use UI-bootstrap, or other Angular 1.x stuff?

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't use such dependencies the simple way. But many libs have created new versions that are compatible. For example see: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. I solved it in the following way:

```
// modules.js
(function (angular) {
    angular.module("shared", []);
    angular.module("user", ["shared"]);
    angular.module("admin", ["shared"]);
})(window.angular);
```

Such structure allows to use factories, services, directives attached to the *shared* module in other modules.